# Openproject mail configuration issue

Tags: ruby, bitnami, openproject

I was using Bitnami Openproject instance and my team loves it. Thanks to the Openproject developers!
But the problem is, users are not receiving any mail when a work package is created or updates. 
I have configured mail in the configuration.yml file as stated in forums and changed user settings to receive mails and **the test mail successfully worked.**
But, when developers are creating an work package, no mail is generated.
It will be nice if anybody can help or provide any suggestions.

With Best Regards

Dip

Answer (score 0):

There is a [wiki guide on how to configure e-mails](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_OpenProject#How_to_configure_the_email_settings_of_OpenProject.3f), with a note on how to enable mail notifications for all projects:

> If you want to receive all the notifications you need to set an extra configuration on the admin panel. For that you can click on OpenProject Admin->My account (on the top-right corner). Then check the "Email notifications" menu and set "For any event on all my projects".

If you are using Windows, you might have to follow some workarounds to enable [delayed_jobs](https://community.bitnami.com/t/activate-background-jobs-in-openproject/37499/3).